# Determining the first combination of 2 numbers in an array that have a sum of X

Tags: arrays, data-structures

Given an array of numbers and a separate number, how would you determine the first combination of 2 numbers in that array that would total this single other number?

Comment: Explain your question more...

Comment: What do you mean by combination? Product, sum, XOR, side-by-side...

Comment: Also, what is your definition of "first" in this case? I could jump around randomly and my first combination could appear anywhere. Does this meet your criteria?

Comment: This does sound like a homework assignment, but the question seems too simple to feel like I'm doing someone's work to answer it. It's nice to help people understand some concept, and if this really is an assignment, it's easy enough that if you don't understand how the answer to it works, you have much bigger problems to worry about. Meaning, you won't pass your exam if you can't answer this for yourself.

Comment: This is typical interview question but I can see it being assigned as homework or something. The simplest solution is O(n^2) - for every number just go over all others and find that add up to the sum. The fun part is to get it work as O(n). But you should try to solve it yourself...

Answer (score 1):

```
for( i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    if( arr[i] + arr[i+1] == x )
         return i;
}
```

Right and if "first combination" does not mean "first consecutive", then you'd need:

```
for( i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++ )
{
    for( j=i+1; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++ )
    {
        if( arr[i] + arr[j] == x )
            return i, j;
    }
}
```

Note that this is pseudo code. Since you didn't specify a language you will have to handle types and acceptable return values yourself.

Comment: I think the question is asking for any two numbers that will add up to the desired value, not consecutive numbers. Would need two for loops

Comment: I know this is pseudocode, but I see you're returning two variables. All of the programming languages I know just allow the returning of one variable, out of curiosity, is there one that lets you have multiple returns?

Comment: @cost Not that I know of. Being kinda lazy as I didn't wanna go into defining the return construction. A language that lets you define arrays on the fly can handle one return statement (perl, php, etc), whereas more strictly typed languages won't let you.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses additional data structure to keep track of the difference (expected pair) for each element in the array.

```
for(int index=0; index<arr.size();index++) 
{
  if(expectedPair.contains(arr[index]))
  {
    pair = new Pair(expectedPair.get(arr[index]), index);
    break;
  }
  expectedPair.put(interestedNumber-arr[index],index); // TODO: handle case where duplicate numbers come up 
}
return pair;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
for (i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < array_size; ++j)
    {
        if (array[i] + array[j] == desired_value)
        {
            // return these two numbers
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a very large array, you could speed up the search process by sorting it, and doing a binary search. Something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
    if (binary_search(sorted_array, array_size, desired_value - array[i])
    {
        ...    
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorting an array is much more expensive then iterating it. If you *create* the array sorted, like a heap, then you have a point, however you must then provide for the case where array[i] = desired_value / 2.

Comment: I think it would be faster with a larger array though. The runtime of our answers would have a runtime of n^2, where this would have a runtime of nlog(n)+n (nlog(n) is the runtime of sorting, right?). With a very very large array, there would be some big speed improvements.